# Unable To Connect To My Virtual Machine (Windows) Using RDP

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, azureportal

I have decided to ask this question here after failing at a lot of Youtube/Google research.

I am not very experienced with virtual machines, cloud computing, RDPs etc. I just use RDP for some educational purposes to do my research.

The issue is, I used to simply start the instance from Azure portal and start RDP on my laptop windows, enter the public IP, username and password and connected to the virtual machine and started doing my work from there.

However, today, when I wanted to log in to my virtual machine, I couldn't and it took me to a different XVNC screen after entering username and password at RDP.

I have no idea what it is and how do I connect to my RDP? Since, it always says 'login failed for display 0' despite me entering correct username and password.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuBHS.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated in this regards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you did not set the username/password correctly.

The session manager tries to use your username/password to unlock the screen. When the username/password are incorrect you get the login failed for display 0 message.

And try to reset  Virtual Machine Password. Check  with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/reset-rdp) to reset the VM Password.And you may try using **mstsc.exe**  client software that allow to connect
computer via RDP

And There are some steps to be performed before connecting to Virtual Machine. check with this  [link](https://www.isumsoft.com/computer/how-to-use-virtual-machine-over-remote-desktop-connection.html)  where you can find step by step procedure.

And also check with  this  [link](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip9.html)  to connect VM through RDP.

Comment: Thank you for commenting Shruti. Please note that I have been using these Azure Windows VMs as RDP for quite some time now and I didn't make any changes to my system recently and it was working fine until yesterday when I wanted to log into the VM and it is taking me to this XRDP screen. Previously, what I did was just open up the Microsoft RDP client, enter username and password and it connected to the VM rightaway but now it takes me to this XRDP screen where I enter the username and password but it doesn't connect and gives error. I have tried resetting password as well but same issue.